# Can XSD elements have more than one <annotation>?

Tags: xsd, annotations

I have a common data schema in XSD that is used by two different applications, A and B, each uses the data differently. I want to document the different business rules per application. Can I do this?

```
<xs:complexType name="Account">
   <xs:annotation app="A">
      <xs:documentation>
        The Account entity must be used this way for app A
      </xs:documentation>
   </xs:annotation>
   <xs:annotation app="B">
      <xs:documentation>
         The Account entity must be used this way for app B
      </xs:documentation>
   </xs:annotation>
   <xs:complexContent>
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`appinfo` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256134.aspx) is used within an `annotation` element, and specifies information to be used by applications:

```
<xs:annotation>
  <xs:appinfo>Any well-formed XML content here</xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>
```

Since any XML content is valid, you can create your own app-specific metadata and put it in the `appinfo` element.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently not, since the XML Schema specification states that annotations, when they are used, must appear [at the beginning](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#CommVers) of an element's content. However, the `annotation` element can have as many [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-1-20041028/structures.html#element-documentation) (or `appinfo`) elements as you wish. You can distinguish these elements using attributes. You can also have multiple children (of any type) within a `documentation` element.

So, one way of writing your schema might look like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="Account">
   <xs:annotation >
      <xs:documentation app="A">
        The Account entity must be used this way for app A
      </xs:documentation>
      <xs:documentation app="B">
         The Account entity must be used this way for app B
      </xs:documentation>
   </xs:annotation>
   <xs:complexContent>
 ...
```